# Web Api and Angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to implement search feature. I wrote an action method that accepts a query and then returns  a  list of item. First, i dont know how to call it from my angularjs service because all the ways I've tried seemed not to work.

```
public IHttpActionResult GetPeople(string query) {
    var results =db.People.Where(q=>q.Name.Contains(query));
    return OK(results) 
}
```

There's another method that only returns all d items in my database with the same GetPeople () but with no parameter.

I tried calling it in my angularjs service as

```
Search : function (q) {
   var deffered = $q.defer();
   $http.get("/api/People/"+q).success(deffered.resolve).error(deffered.reject);
   return deffered.promise;
}
```

How do I call d GetPeople method that takes a search value

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$http({ method:'GET', url:"/api/People/", params: { query:q}})
```

It could also be your server-side method declaration. Do you have a Route attribute mapping GetPeople to api/People?

Answer (score 0):

a little tip, before trying to call the api programatically  try calling it manually, 
it would help if you can share you're route config,
but anyway i think this should work -

```
Search : function (q) {
       var deffered = $q.defer();
       $http.get("/api/People?query?"+q).success(deffered.resolve).error(deffered.reject);
        return deffered.promise;
}
```

on default web api accepts the parameters in the action as query parameters,
so this should work,
if you want a "prettier" route you should create a new route in the RouteConfig section of youre app.